# What are good resources to learn KNN text classification using Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, recommender-system, text-classification

I found the KNN image classification tutorial using MNIST dataset and was able to lear how it's working.

Are there any resources that describe to apply the same KNN algorithm to text classification. I have a shops list(hardware, electrical store, grocery store etc.) as the data set. I'm trying to build a model to suggest the best store to visit if i search something. For example, if i search "Buy a ice cream" it should suggest "Grocery store".

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Mind that image classification and text classification are very different, it's not becaluse kNN works for images that it would work for text (in fact kNN is rarely used with text). Also how do you plan to train your text 'grocery' classification system, do you have some large enough labelled data?

Comment: Thanks for the response and the knowledge. Yes I have a list of store names and phrases

Comment: Since you have some labeled data it means that you can treat this as a standard text classification problem. You can find many tutorials about this online, it's very common. The main difficulty is representing the text as features, and your text is probably very short so it's not sure that standard preprocessing methods would work.